# Is there a way to deduce alias templates to template template parameter while still preserving its property of being deduced context

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, template-aliases

After a while I discovered again a power of template *template-parameters*. See e.g. the following snippet:

```
template <template <class> class TT, class T>
void foo(TT<T>) {
}

template <class T>
using typer = T;

int main() {
    foo<typer>(int{});
}
```

The alias template is passed to the template as a template *template-parameter* and is used further to detect the other parameter of the template as it is deduced context. Beauty!

However just when the alias template itself need to be deduced it looks like the compilers get crazy:

```
template <template <class> class>
struct tag{};

template <template <class> class TT, class T>
void foo(tag<TT>, TT<T>) {
}

template <class T>
using typer = T;

int main() {
    foo(tag<typer>{}, int{});
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TZFKYT3f4P6dPJW2)

Compilers of course are right as `TT` can be deduced from both `tag<TT>` as well as `TT<T>`  parameters of `foo`, and the `int{}` doesn't match the template template with type parameter pattern. Is there any way to preserve the deduction context for `T` but make `TT` non-deduced context in `TT<T>`?

P.S. My intentions are pure and this is just a theoretical question with no Y problem behind it.

Comment: Honestly I can't see any use neither for the first _beautifulness_ nor for the second attempt. Anyway the question is intriguing, +1.

Comment: @skypjack as I said I haven't even think about possible usages so you might be right there isn't any...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier/clearer to write something like:

```
template <template <class> class TT, class T>
void foo(tag<TT>, T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T,TT<T>>::value >* = 0 )
```

or the less constrained

```
template <template <class> class TT, class T>
void foo_impl( tag<TT>, TT<T> ){}

template <template <class> class TT, class T>
void foo( tag<TT> a, T b ){ foo_impl<TT>( a, b ); }
```

as a side note, this shows that the (non normative) note in the standard claiming that *An alias template name is never deduced* is somewhat inaccurate ...